# undefined method nil "group_by"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm overlooking what should be a simple solution. I keep getting the error:

```
NoMethodError in LifetimesController#index
undefined method `deadline' for #<Class:0x007f88a3c19bb0>
```

This is because one of the `lifetime` challenges has a `nil` `:deadline`. Adding deadlines are optional.

How can I `group_by` only the `lifetime` challenges that have a `:deadline` present?

**controller**

```
def index
  @lifetimes = current_user.lifetimes.unaccomplished
  @lifetime_months = @lifetimes.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_month }
end
```

**model**

```
scope :unaccomplished, -> { where(accomplished: nil) }
```

**schema**

```
  create_table "lifetimes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "deadline"
    t.boolean  "accomplished"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
  end
```

I was unsuccessful in adding a `nil` or `.present?` conditional to any of the above code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `nil`. You're invoking `deadline` on a class that doesn't respond to the method `deadline`, not on `nil`. The error is showing you very clearly that you *do not* have a `nil` value.

Comment: I'm confused @meagar. So what's the solution here if I want to list out all the `lifetimes` by `deadline` for those that have a `deadline`?

Comment: @meagar the error goes away if I add a `deadline` to the `lifetime` I had created without one, but like I said I'd like to give the user the option to leave out deadlines. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Could you post the relevant parts of the schema.rb file and your lifetime model?

Comment: Added schema @Oleander

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Could you also open a console and post the output from `Lifetime` (just enter `Lifetime` and hit enter). It as to be in the same environment as the one you getting the exception in.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that finally worked:

`scope :unaccomplished, -> { where.not(deadline: nil) }`

I tried very similar things in the past, but only this seemed to work. Thanks for the help!